# Auto redirect to another page In Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am making payment through paypal. After payment completion it redirect to my website(complete.php) page. I have code in complete.php that will update the credit in database. when i refresh the same page then it automatically update credits in database. I want to update credit only when payment is done. The code i am using in complete.php is:

```
      $db       = JFactory::getDBO();
        $result = null;

        $user   = JFactory::getUser();
        if ($user->guest) {
            return false;
        }

        $query = 'SELECT credit' .
                 ' FROM #__vodes_credits' .
                 ' WHERE userid = ' . (int) $user->id
                 ;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadResult();

        $result_final=$result+20;


$query = 'update #__vodes_credits SET credit='.$result_final.
                 ' WHERE userid = ' . (int) $user->id
                 ;
//echo $query;

//echo $query;
 $db->setQuery($query);


        $result = $db->loadResult();
if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
            JError::raiseWarning( 500, $db->stderr());
        }

        return $result;


?>

Please help me to sought it out.
```

Comment: Please try asking your question at the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site ;)

Comment: Also what is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a COOKIE before the payment and then destroy that COOKIE after the first time the user has visited the complete.php, that will work.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to redirect, I am not sure where are you writing your code but try the below code

```
$app=JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setRedirect('url','msg');
```